# Regular expression for a binary string containing even number of 0's

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

To get the regular expression I made a finite automata as the following (not sure if you can directly write regular expression without it):

[image]

The regular expression for the above according to me should be $(1+01^*0)^*$ but elsewhere I have seen it can be $(1^*01^*01^*)^*$. Why is it different?

Comment: http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs143/cs143.1112/materials/handouts/WA1-sols.pdf

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954586/regular-expression-for-strings-that-cointains-a-and-an-even-number-of-bs

Comment: In the same way, $(a+b)^*$ and $(a^*ba^*)^*$ represent the same language.

Comment: Years later... The second one (1*01*01*)* doesn't accept any string with only 1's, so it's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (infinitely) many regular expressions for every regular language. Your approach gives you one (good job on a structured approach!), others give you others.

Consider, for instance, two distinct yet equivalent NFA translated using Thompson's construction.

Answer (score 3):

(1∗01∗01∗)∗ is actually wrong because it doesn't handle a string consisting of all 1's

Comment: Yes the my opinion: the best RE: `(1*01*(00)*1*01*)*`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your DFA, you can repeat $1$ zero or more times ($1^*$), then a $0$, then again $1$ zero or more times ($1^*$), and a $0$ to finish at the final state, where again you can go $1$ zero or more times, in all $1^* 0 1^* 0 1^*$; but the above game you can repeat at will, for $(1^* 0 1^* 0 1^*)^*$ in all.

"Hand translating" a DFA into a regular expression can be done in several ways, you could also take $(1^* 0 1^* 0)^*$ to go to the final state, and only at the end handle possible final $1$s, for $(1^* 0 1^* 0)^* 1^*$

Answer (score 0):

Both of the expression will give the same answer. (1+0)* means any combination of 1 and 0 any number of times. So equivalently (1+01*0)* can be inferred. Which is the same as second expression.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of $(1+0)^*$, which doesn't appear in either of the regular expressions in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This question was posted quite a long time ago. But I post the answer for any further help of desirous.

Both the answers are perhaps wrong. Your answer cannot generate $1010$ and the other cannot generate $1$. So what you may try is like this.

1. First construct regex for smallest even number of $0$'s which will
   be $R=00$. Now $1$ can be put anywhere any number of times in the
   $R$. So now $R$ will convert to $R=1^*01^*01^*$.      Now we
   construct regex for any even number of $0$. So we simply use the
   'star' operator. and thus $R=(1^*01^*01^*)^*$.      But notice that
   strings containing only $1$, i.e., no occurrence of $0$'s must be
   accepted by the automata because zero number of $0$'s is still
   acceptable since $0$ is also an even number but this regex is
   declining $1^*$ to be accepted. So we just take union with $1$ and
   thus the final regex will be $R=(1+1^*01^*01^*)^*$.
2. Another answer could be $1^*(01^*01^*)^*$.  I think in the second answer posted by the OP, there was a typo on behalf of the book writer by just misplacing $()$.